# Can't repo init android source code mirror

Tags: android, init, mirror, repo

I'm trying to mirror Android source code but it's not possible.
I had to upgrade python to 3.6 and update repo.

However I can't repo init android source mirror.

> jeffrey@devserver:/home1/aosp/mirror$ repo init -u
> https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror Downloading
> Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo Downloading
> manifest from https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/main.py", line 627, in 
> _Main(sys.argv[1:])   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/main.py", line 601, in _Main
> result = run()   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/main.py", line 594, in 
> run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/main.py", line 260, in _Run
> result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 519, in Execute
> self._SyncManifest(opt)   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 220, in
> _SyncManifest
> default_branch = m.ResolveRemoteHead()   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1914, in
> ResolveRemoteHead
> output = self.bare_git.ls_remote('-q', '--symref', '--exit-code', name, 'HEAD')   File "/home1/aosp/mirror/.repo/repo/project.py", line
> 3034, in runner
> (self._project.name, name, p.stderr)) error.GitError: manifests ls-remote: usage: git ls-remote [--heads] [--tags]
> [--upload-pack=]
> [-q | --quiet] [--exit-code] [--get-url] [ [...]]

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your 'git ls-remote' does not have '--symref' parameter, maybe you need to update the git version.